# CSS Menu - left align image and right align menu items

Tags: html, css

I have this css menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/L65dx02m/1/

i want to be able to right align the menu and left align an image (as if it were a menu item but with no hover)

i tried adding a class around the image and using `float:left;` and a class around the menu items with `float:right` but this done nothing

Comment: The image is supposed to be in an <img> tag not an <a>

Comment: it was, i just missed a '>' - http://jsfiddle.net/L65dx02m/4/

Comment: i want the menu a little bit like this site (alignment) - https://www.cranialink.com/

Comment: float the image to the left but surround it in an (a) tag and style it -- http://jsfiddle.net/znyo0ove/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your `<img>` and `<ul>` in a div and then float them. For my example I used the `<nav>` as the wrapper and then styled the children (floating them, setting the height to 100%, etc)

```
<nav>
     <img>
     <ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L65dx02m/6/

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
<li><a <img src="" width="130px" /></a></li>
```

to

```
<li style="float: left; text-align: left;"><a> <img src="" width="130px" /></a></li>
```

and add

```
text-align: right;
```

to your style under .int_menu {}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser support you may opt to consider a `flexbox` solution to your problem if it was acceptable.

You can check out a nice reference to `flexbox` over @ css-tricks.com [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I've put together the following snippet for reference, available on jsbin.com [here](http://jsbin.com/gutobedose/edit?html,css,output).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.myHeader {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.myHeader__nav a {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.myHeader__nav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <header class="myHeader">
    <a class="myHeader__title">
      <img src="" alt="mySite">
    </a>
    <nav class="myHeader__nav">
      <a>Homepage</a>
      <a>About us</a>
      <a>Services</a>
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Support</a>
      <a>Contact us</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

I would personally be careful with having too many menu items though and look to condense them if possible into dropdowns etc.

Hope that helps you out!